# How to disable the animated hiding toolbar items?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, storyboard

I have a simple interface of two table views, navigation controller and toolbar. The toolbar of each view has the same bar items (constructed using storyboard). 
When I push a new view toolbar items of current tableview fade out with animation and when toolbar items of next tableview fade in with animation also. The result is a blink of items when I switch tableviews.

How can I make switch views without animation of bar items? To previous elements become invisible and the next elements become visible without animation?

Comment: What code are you using to implement the animation?

Comment: no code. just storyboard.

Comment: No animation can be implement without code or from nib file.

Comment: What do I need to disable the animation in code?

Comment: Ok you mean you are navigating to another controller where you have the 2nd tableview? In dat case you can check the value of hidesBottomBarWhenPushed in the first controller. There will be animation if its set to YES.

Comment: I set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO in all controllers but it does'n work. Because toolbar is always visible but toolbar items has blink when I push a new view..